# Xpath syntax with HTML parsing in iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, xpath, syntax

I'm using Xpath in my iOS app, I want to parse an HTML page from Wikipedia and grab some informations.
I have a problem with my xpathQueryString to catch the "(a) (/a)" attributes with this kind of HTML code :

```
<td>
    <span style="display:none" class="sortkey">Eglise Saint-Roch !</span>
    <a href="/wiki/%C3%89glise_Saint-Roch_(Paris)" title="Église Saint-Roch (Paris)">Église Saint-Roch</a>
</td>
```

This is my NSString query :

```
@"//table[@class]//tr//td[1] | //table[@class]//tr//td[1]/a | //table[@class]//tr//td[1]/span
```

The span node is parsing but not the a node.

"/a" is supposed to catch the first (a)(/a) from "td" right ?
According to http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp :

```
//book/title | //book/price Selects all the title AND price elements of all book elements
```

I need your help, because I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Thanks !

Comment: Strange indeed. Works for me.

Comment: With the path `//table[@class]//tr//td[1]/a` any `a` child element of the first `td` descendant element of any `tr` descendant of any `table` element with a `class` attribute is selected. If your path `//table[@class]//tr//td[1]/span` finds the `span` in the snippet you have posted then the other path should find the `a` as well. If that does not work then the real input is different or your real code uses different path expressions or your XPath processor is broken.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried to parse only with `//table[@class]//tr//td[1] | //table[@class]//tr//td[1]/a` but I have the same problem, when there is a span node before an a node, I don't go inside the a ... I don't understand why it's not working.